# How to scroll QListWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I select some item in `QListWidget` when it's creating using `listWidget->item(sel)->setSelected(true)`

But visible area of `QListWidget` is in the beginning even if the selected item is below fit items.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you want the last selected item to be visible?

Comment: Selected item can be anywhere in this list I want to set scrollbar to 
the appropriate position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move the scrollbar to make a specific item visible, use scrollToItem:

```
listWidget->scrollToItem(listWidget->item(sel));
```